# SWT generates BAD MAGIC NUMBER on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swt

I was trying to get a Java SWT application running on scientific Linux 6.4 (64-bit) machine.  It was generating a BAD Magic Number, so I decided to try to get a simple Java application working on it, and got the same results.

Using a SWT snippet which simply displays a Shell.  I complied the application using (oracle's JDK 1.0.7U45 32-bit) in eclipse and ran it on my 32-bit windows box.  The application used the 32-bit swt.jar file available from eclipse for windows.

So, I moved this simple Java app over to my SL6.4 computer, which has gnome installed. Then, replaced the swt.jar with the on available from eclipse (swt-4.2.2-gtk-linux-x86_64.zip).
When trying running this app, it is returning "invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error".  This is the same result regardless of trying to run it with OpenJDK 64-bit Server VM (1.7.0_51) or Oracle's 64-bit server VM (1.7.0_45-b18).

I must be missing something simple in the installation.

---

found the issue... used a semicolon instead of a colon as a classpath separator.